# Unable to find BeanIO mapping file when uploading Lambda function

Tags: java, aws-lambda, bean-io

I have a java program that writes to a file using beanIO. The program runs fine on my local environment and acts as expected. I first wrote this program on my local environment, and then have been uploading it as an AWS Lambda function, so it *was not* initially created as an AWS Lambda function.

I use an Eclipse plugin to upload my code as an AWS Lambda function and test it using console.aws.amazon.com online. When I test it, I get an exception returned back:

```
org.beanio.BeanIOConfigurationException: BeanIO mapping file 'foo.xml' not 
found on classpath\n\tat
```

The line that the error occurs on is this:

```
StreamFactory sf = StreamFactory.newInstance();
sf.loadResource("foo.xml"); // right here
```

I have tried putting foo.xml in the same package as the new

I'm new to beanIO and AWS Lambda. Do I need to configure the location of foo.xml differently to have it be referenced properly when uploading to Lambda? Since it works fine on my local environment, I am confused as to  what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up fixing the issue by removing the source folder of foo.xml and adding it as a source again. I'm not sure why it messed up in the first place.